# React-Native this.props.navigation.navigate is not working inside function get_id()

Tags: react-native

I am using React-Native to implement Home screen with if-condition inside get_Id(), In my page i am using get_Id() function to get the userId from  AsyncStorage,
if i didn't get the userId i need to redirect the screen to the 
login scrren for that i used 
 `this.props.navigation.navigate("LogIn");`

But i am getting error

```
Error:Element type is invalid:expected a string(for built-in components)or a class/function 
(for composite component) but got:undefined.
You likely forgot to export your component from the files it's definedi , 
or you might have mixed up default and named imports 
check the render method of HeaderBackButton
```

My code:

```
get_Id = async () => {
    try {
      const userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('USER_ID')
      if (userId !== null) {
        this.setState({ userId: userId })
      } else {
        this.setState({ userId: null });

        this.props.navigation.navigate("LogIn");  

      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('AddPost Screen : get_Id No user Found')

    }
  }
```

check my code if anyone find the error in my code please let me know the solution.

Thank you .Happy Coding ..

Comment: are you able to see if this.props has the navigation field??  this.props is undefined or it's ok?? let's try with async function()  instead async () =>

Comment: Thank you for the reply i am already tried with    async get_Id() { , 
i am getting this error when update the react-native packages

Comment: Please post  related ```HeaderBackButton``` code

Comment: Thank you for the replay , but there is no code , i am getting the error in get_Id() function

Comment: ```Element type is invalid:expected a string``` issue is not related to your ```get_Id``` function. Share your code where you call ```get_Id```

Answer (score 0):

I Just found the solution for my problem by removing React-Navigation 4.X related code , I got this error because recently i upgraded from React Navigation-4.X to React Navigation-5.x ,
Do to React Navigation-4.X upgrade i got so many errors related to navigation .

```
import { NavigationEvents } from '@react-navigation/native';

<NavigationEvents
   onDidFocus={() => Alert.alert('Home')}
   onDidFocus={console.log('Home Screen')
/>
```

I just removed above code to overcome the error .